# Issue to upload files to sentry with NX

Tags: angular, sentry, angular12, nomachine-nx, nx-monorepo

I'm trying to upload the maps to sentry *(self instance*) but even getting code **0** as a outcome the files aren't showing on artifacts in sentry, i'm using Nx and uploading file from Angular App (**nx 12.10, Angular 12, "@sentry/angular": "7.47.0"**).

**That's the cmd:**

```
"upload": "sentry-cli --url https://sentry.production.mycompany.com/ sourcemaps upload --org=mycompany --project=project-cms --strict --rewrite sentry_environment=production --release=--release ./dist --url-prefix='~/dist'",
```

Does anyone faced for this before to help me :)

[image]

I've tried to exec the commands with release tag and without, created many releases since this sentry version do not allows upload bundle source maps without release, however not success.

Comment: what is the log output of sentry cli?

Comment: @LucaForstner no logs over there, but if i upload via api it works well, but via sentry cli nothing appears in artifacts.

Comment: sentry cli should log a bunch of things when it runs. Is there really nothing? If so, something is majorly messed up.

Comment: yeah! no log... i put a screenshot maybe someone knows how to upload using this archtecture

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that its title summarizes the problem you are having rather than just being a repeat of the tags. See [ask] for more tips on creating good questions.